# a way to see prebuild steps output in console?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, console, pre-build-event

I compile in pre build step another project that takes time -  don't see any output in console I'm just waiting. Is there a way to output it to console as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to change the verbosity of the MS Build (I think).

Goto **Tools**, **Options...**, **Project and Solutions**, **Build and Run** and change the **MSBuild project build output verbosity**

[image: Options]